# automatically deleting data from a table in a database after some time

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:
One is request table and the other is acceptance table. The acceptance table has a foreign key of the request table.
If a data is inserted into the request table and after some time say 30mins and there is no acceptance, then the request should be deleted from the  request table. 
How do I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: You can create a cron that runs in each 30min and inside it write some code to delete your unwanted record

Comment: @AnkurTiwari That could make some records to stay for up to 59 minutes, if he is OK with that , I would go with this option.

Comment: @Accountantم He can manage the time of cron according to his requirement

Comment: The best idea would be to not delete at all. Make the records time-dependant and delete the old ones periodically.

Comment: 'If a data is inserted into the request table and after some time say 30mins and there is no acceptance' - parse all of the request table every 30 minutes? Might get a bit slow eventually.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using Mysql method, [Event Scheduler](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)

```
CREATE EVENT [IF NOT EXIST]  event_name
ON SCHEDULE schedule
DO
event_body
```

Comment: @Kofi Atta, if the answer helps, please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a column named `created_at`, let's say you have a column named `accepted`, no run a cron every once in a while which does:

```sql
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `accepted` = 0 AND `created_at` < DATE_SUB(NOW, INTERVAL 30 minute);
```

Comment: The problem with the cron solution it has to run every second(theoretically) if he needs the records to be deleted after exactly 30 minutes, otherwise some records will stay more than 30 minutes.

Comment: Mysql event scheduler is really useful for this type of thing as well.